# Run multiple commands in shell script using `find` and `xargs`

Tags: linux, shell, sh

I'm attempting to `echo` the filename then `sqlcmd` directly after however I simply cannot figure out how to concatenate the statements in a way that works.

I have tried:

- Creating a new function (apparently can't be done like this in shell only bash)
- Separating with a semi colon (both escaped and without)
- Using the double && as per this example

Any tips please.

```
find "./src/ALs/Database/SQL" -iname "*.sql" | sort -n | xargs -0 -I % sh -c 'echo % && sqlcmd -S $SQL_HOST -d Database -U $SQL_USER -P $SQL_PWD -i %'
```

Comment: Do not __ever__ use `xargs -I % sh -c '...%...'`; that way lies serious security bugs.

Comment: Consider what happens if you have a file with `$(rm -rf ~)` in its name; worse, `$(rm -rf ~)'$(rm -rf ~)'`, so it gets expanded whether or not it's in a single-quoted context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that if you remove `-0` from xargs it'll do what you expect. That flag is for null-byte-separated input, whereas you are passing it newline-separated input.

To work with null-byte-separated records throughout the pipeline use `find ... -print0`, `sort -z` and `xargs -0`. This is the most robust way to pass records through a pipeline (it won't break, no matter what your filenames are).

```
find "./src/AdviserLinks/Database/SQL" -iname "*.sql" -print0 | 
  sort -zn | 
  xargs -0 -n1 sh -c 'echo "$0" && 
    sqlcmd -S "$SQL_HOST" -d WebSupportDatabase -U "$SQL_USER" -P "$SQL_PWD" -i "$0"'
```

This assumes that the `$SQL` variables are `export`-ed to the environment.

I have replaced `-I %` with `-n1`, which will process records one at a time. Each filename is passed to `sh` as `$0`, which can be used safely; there is no risk that the contents of the record is interpreted as shell syntax, as was the case with `-I %` in your attempt. Note that this means that a separate child shell is invoked for every file, and it would be more efficient to use a loop as in [Charles' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63743560/2088135).

As for using separate statements vs `&&`, that depends on whether you want the execution of the second command to be conditional on the success of first command.

Comment: Definitely the better solution is to keep the `-0` and instead add `-print0` to `find`; the bug is you need to have neither, or both, but both is obviously more correct. A much, much better solution still is `find -exec`.

Comment: Thanks very much, unfortunately I'm getting the following error: `./src/ALs/Database/SQL/10 Schemas/10 [AL].sql
Sqlcmd: './src/AL/Database/SQL/10': Invalid filename.`  There is a space in the filename after the `10`

Comment: @tripleee the reason I didn't propose `find -exec` was the `sort` in between, I wasn't aware that could be done as part of `find`.

Comment: Yeah, the `sort` complicates matters if it's strictly necessary.

Comment: Ah yes, thank you very much! Really appreciate the help there, I was missing the inner `'`

Comment: Using `-I` to substitute a value into the `-c` argument of `sh` is inherently unsafe, because it means the values you're substituting in go through the shell's parser. Consider `$(rm -rf ~)'$(rm -rf ~)'` as an example of a substring that, if put in place of a `%` inside a `sh -c` argument, will _always_ execute no matter what the quoting context is (single-quoted, double-quoted, or unquoted).

Answer (score 1):

Aiming to combine both safety and performance (invoking `sh` only once per list of sql files that fit on a command line):

```
find "./src/AdviserLinks/Database/SQL" -iname "*.sql" -print0 | 
  sort -zn | 
  xargs -0 sh -c '
    for arg do
      echo "$arg"
      sqlcmd -S "$SQL_HOST" -d WebSupportDatabase -U "$SQL_USER" -P "$SQL_PWD" -i "$arg"
    done
  ' _
```

Note:

- We aren't using the `-I` argument to `xargs` at all. Instead of using a sigil, we let xargs concatenate as many items as possible to the end of the argument list for `sh`.
- Within the `sh` command, `for arg do` loops over `"$@"` by default; thus, it assigns `$1`, `$2`, etc. in turn to the variable named `arg`, so that just one copy of `sh` can process several SQL files.
- We're letting all the expansions of values like `SQL_HOST`, `SQL_USER` and `SQL_PWD` be performed **by the child shell**, instead of attempting to do them in the parent (note that this *does* require that these values be exported to the environment, rather than merely set as process-local shell variables). This change means that a SQL password that might have characters meaningful to the shell doesn't risk being parsed as syntax.